# Show Notifications in Android Without Using Intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, notifications

I am a beginner in android .I want to show notification in my app . I use the following code

```
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)  getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification  = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Hello";
        CharSequence contentText = "Welcome ";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);       
        notificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

But my problem is whenever run my app the intent is loaded with icon .Then the icon is show in the status bar . how to show notifications without using intent ? please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you want to show some quick notification, toasts come to mind:

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Notification!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
```

You can change how long the toast is shown with duration.